# My BrowserHelperObject is detected by avg as a malware, what is going wrong

Tags: internet-explorer-8, malware, avg-antivirus

I'm building a BrowserHelperObject in C++ for Internet Explorer 8. It is a friendly add-on that gives you functionality in a sidebar.

The thing is that when you download the add-on executable from the web, AVG (AntiVirusGuard) detects the executable file as a malware. I did a lot of research and I can't find a way to not being seen as a bad malware. I know that BrowserHelperObject are often seen as malware, but mine is just a good and friendly add-on.

Does anyone as info on how antivirus detection works and what can I do to prevent being seen as a malware. What has to be done to the BHO to pass avg detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit your installer to AVG for them to add to [their whitelist](http://www.avg.com/us-en/whitelist).

Comment: Thank you Daisetsu, that was something i needed to know. You rock !